# How to compare models using id's Django

Tags: python, django

Can anyone please help in tackling the following problem?

Suppose I have a model named `Answer` and a form for user input named `CheckAnswer`.

What I want is that when a particular `Question` page is openend and the user types the answer, it should get checked with the corresponding answer
The answer from the model can be accessed using the id. but how can i specify the id of question page that opens up and link it to the answer id.
Below are the codes attached
**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Answer
from django.core.exceptions import ObjectDoesNotExist

class CheckAnswer(forms.Form):
    your_answer=forms.CharField(label='Answer')
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data=super(CheckAnswer,self).clean()
        response=cleaned_data.get("your_answer")

        try:
            p = Answer.objects.get(id=1,answer__iexact=response)
        except Answer.DoesNotExist:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Wrong Answer.")
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.views.generic import *
from . import models
from django import forms
from .forms import CheckAnswer
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
# Create your views here.
@login_required
def Arena1(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = CheckAnswer(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('thanks')
    else:
        form=CheckAnswer()
    return render(request,'levels/arena1.html',{'form':form})
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User=get_user_model()
users=User.objects.all()
# Create your models here.
class Answer(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=10,unique=True)
    answer=models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering= ["-name"]
```

Comment: Where's your Question model?  This is quite similar to the tutorial app in the official Django docs. I suggest you read through that tutorial, since it explains things very clearly. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: questions are basically various html templates. 
They are not stored in databse. Basically i have a tab for questions in my nav bar which would redirect to the particular question and user can enter their answer. Now i want to ask that how to connect with the webpage that is opened with id of my Answer model. For eg.. if Q1 tab is clicked and user inputs his answer then it should be checked with answer 1 of Model Answer only.

Comment: If there's only one correct answer to each question, and you don't want to save the questions in the database, why do you use a database at all, then?

Comment: what if Q1 has answer "delhi" and Q3 has answer "Kerala" and in Q1. User types Kerala as answer it would say that answer is correct being in the list of answers but actually it is not the answer for corresponding question....Is there anyway to tackle this?

Comment: Before writing the answer can you clarify `id of question page that opens up and link it to the answer id.` line meaning a bit. Is it like Q-id-1 has one answer say ans-id-1 or it has multiple answers? And also can Ans with id-1 can be an answer to multiple question?

Comment: Q1 should have id same as that of answer 1
so that there is one to one relation between answer and question.
each answer has only one question,no multiple questions

Comment: Add Question in models too and every answer should have a foreign key linking to its question.

Comment: I created a model for questions and also have a foreign key for answers. so what should be my code for problem to get solved...-@VaibhavVishal